# Powershell Variable shows us as command insted of value

Tags: sql, powershell

When I run this script the result does not get inserted into the database only the command I used to get the result.

If I simply output the variables `$Computername` and `$username` to the screen they output correctly

```
$Computername = 'get-wmiobject -query "select csname from win32_operatingsystem" | select-object     csname | ft -hide'
$username = 'Get-Childitem env:username |select value | ft -hide'
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlInsert = @"

insert into info (computername,username)
Values ('$computername','$username')

"@
$Connection.open() 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlInsert
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$SqlCmd.Connection = $Connection
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$Connection.Close()
```

Any Ideas as to how to insert only the variables rather than the commands?

Answer (score 1):

Skip the single quotes, like this.

```
$Computername = get-wmiobject -query "select csname from win32_operatingsystem" | select-object     csname | ft -hide
$username = Get-Childitem env:username |select value | ft -hide
```

Also, you'll find that your code for getting computername and username is the same as this;

```
$env:computername
$env:username
```

Answer (score 1):

Three Things:

1. You are passing Strings to $Computername and $username variable, rather than commands.
   Remove first and last single quote from those variable assignment.
2. Format-Table Cmdlet is used to better format the output at PowerShell console.

   $Computername = get-wmiobject -query "select csname from win32_operatingsystem" | select-object  csname | ft -hide

   Above command gives you a Format object which you can see using

   `$computername | Get-Member`

   This object is not what you want to insert into your Databse.
   Instead use -Expandproperty Parameter of Select-object to get the string value.

   `$Computername = get-wmiobject -query "select csname from win32_operatingsystem" | select-object -ExpandProperty csname`

   `$username = Get-Childitem env:username |select -ExpandProperty value`
3. You are missing a SQLConnection object. OR may be use hid it on purpose :)